# ASP.NET radio button jQuery handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to figure out why my page doesn't fire the radio button change event.

Here's the script I have for it, it's supposed to show a div once the radio button is checked.

```
        $("input[id$='radio1']").change(function () {
        if ($("input[id$=radio1]").is(':checked')) {
            $('#div1').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
```

what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("input[id$='radio1']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#div1").removeClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[id$='radio1']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#div1').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

You should use the `this` object in your function.

Comment: @Victor You're welcome :) (Royi had it first though so his answer should be the accepted one).

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder Sorry... rolled back the change because I was viewing a cached version and thought it was incorrectly edited >.>

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `this` keyword inside the function, instead of asking jQuery to search for elements matching the selector again.

```
$("input[id$='radio1']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#div1').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: uh... He's using the [attribute ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector for the id... hence he needs [id$=radio1]

Comment: you are wrong... hes selector is all the one who starts with !

Comment: Silly me, I've removed that and just left in the second part! thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

try asking in this way if the radio is checked.

```
if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked) {
    $('#div1').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Comment: this won't work with ASP.NET radio because it adds the parent element name when rendering controls.

Comment: you are rigth, so you should use this inside the block. :)